# JOIN in ArcGIS with relationship classes

Tags: join, arcgis

I have a question regarding Esri ArcGIS.

I have a street dataset where each street segment has its own id. Additionally, I have a table where certain routes are defined (each route has its own id again). Each of these routes consist of a set of street segments. For that, I have a table where the relationship between the routes and the street segments is defined (for each segment there is one route).

My goal is to get the information, to which route a segments belongs, into the same table, i.e. I want to have the information about to which route a segment belongs in the same table. I guess that would work vie the JOIN operation, but I couldnt figure it out.

I tried the ArcGIS help but I couldnt find any solution.

Comment: You could try posting this in http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like [Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_linear_referencing/003900000001000000/) where you can use [Create Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000005000000) followed by [Dynamic Segmentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000026000000) to achieve what you describe.

If you have any follow up questions on any of these topics you are welcome to post them on the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).